# Accord de « ni l'un ni l'autre »

Tags: accord, mathématiques

Je voudrais rendre la phrase :

> Examine whether the following function are even, odd or neither.

Devrait-ce être

> Examinez si les fonctions suivantes sont paires, impaires ou ni l'une ni l'autre.

ou

> Examinez si les fonctions suivantes sont paires, impaires ou ni l'un ni l'autre.

?

Comment: Juste pour info, une fonction ni paire ni impaire, c'est quoi par exemple ?

Comment: @Toto : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parit%C3%A9_d%27une_fonction (Even and odd functions)

Comment: Personnellement j'utiliserai la deuxième option mais je n'ai pas vraiment d'arguments à fournir, c'est juste un ressenti.

Comment: @Toto : For instance : cosinus is a even function (paire) ; sinus is an odd one (impaire).

Comment: D'accord, merci.

Comment: @Toto : Merci pour les commentaires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans ce cas on n'accorde pas le pronom « un ».

- Examinez si les fonctions suivantes sont paires, impaires ou ni l'un ni l'autre.

Cet usage est reconnu par LBU (14ième édition, 744 b 1°).

> « L'un » invariable (masculin à valeur de neutre) s'impose si les pronoms
>   renvoient à des syntagmes dépourvus de genre, à des adjectifs, des
>   phrases, etc. : Est-elle sévère et juste ? Ni L'UN ni L'AUTRE. — Ont-elles
>   menti ? Ont-elles trahi ? Elles ont fait L'UN et L'AUTRE
>
> remarque Comp. : En dehors des haleines et des oies sauvages,
>   seuls les pirates à l'époque s'y [au Canada] retrou-
>   vaient. Et pourtant Champlain, qui n'était ni I'UN ni
>   L'AUTRE [= ni l'un de ces animaux ni un pirate], s'y risqua
>   (A. MAILLET, dans la Revue générale, oct, 1993, p.

Comment: Merci. Pourquoi pas ? (intuitivement je sais que vous avez raison:-)!)

Comment: @Dimitris « Pourquoi pas » est la question sur laquelle je me penche encore et je ne trouve pas de référence. Il me semble que je sais qu'il n'y a pas d'accord depuis toujours et sans trop chercher dans ma tête je trouve que la raison serais que les pronoms réfèrent à un état, donc quelque chose de masculin ou neutre ; cependant je ne peux pas affirmer cela.